# How to process uploaded images in Django?

Tags: android, python, django

I've android application that uploads images to django server which hosted on 'pythonanywhere'. The android app works 100% it uploads images into the server
and saves them correctly.

my problem is I want to do some image processing on the received pictures on the server side I know how to do image processing but ''I

The problem is I need to do an image processing code on the uploaded image right after the server catch the image and i don't know to how to do it in my code

I've looked on djagno files on the server and I found models.py

```
    from django.db import models

    class MyImage(models.Model):
       model_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = '', default = 'none/no-img.jpg')
```

I guess the model_pic has the my uploaded photo

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `.save()` model method, but your best bet would be to use a mature and stable image processing package such as [django-imagekit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit). It has some great built-in image processors, and even lets you [create your own.](https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#processors)

Comment: I think you have to override the `.save()` method anyway yeah?  I mean its likely your using other apps, and will need to overrride save to have the other apps and imagekit work together.